# How do I make a turn based redstone game?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

I'm trying to make a redstone game but I'm stuck on part of the circuit.

I have two sides: A and B. Each have 9 inputs. Players use these inputs to submit moves in the game.

The problem I'm having is making it turn-based. After A inputs their move, I need the circuit to ignore any other inputs until B makes theirs (and vice versa). What can I do to force my circuit to work that way?

Comment: You didn't ask any question? Are you trying to show off or do you actually have a problem?

Comment: First, edit your post to be more readable. If you don't, you'll find most people won't bother. Secondly, please show us what you've tried.

Comment: Oh, I get it. It took a bit of time to figure out but OP's question is actually pretty straightforward (even if the answer may not be). If anything, trying to put in detail makes it *less* readable. Imma fix it now.

Answer (score 1):

If you are happy using command blocks, try this. When someone presses the finish turn button (if there is one) a command block deletes their buttons/other inputs using `/fill [co-ords] air` and using `/fill [co-ords] stone/wooden_button [number of rotation]` to give the other player their buttons.

It would look like this:
https://prnt.sc/i0jzsj